# Azure AD - Instance & SignUpSignInPolicyId Advice

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, active-directory

I'm watching a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJH43uOwZm0&t=382s that shows how to set up **Azure B2C Identity Connection Settings**. In the video, it has the developer creating settings against an **Azure B2C AD** as below...

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://{TENANT-NAME}.b2clogin.com",
    "Domain": "https://{TENANT-NAME}.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "https://{TENANT-ID}.onmicrosoft.com",
    "ClientId": "https://{CLIENT-ID}.onmicrosoft.com",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "Scopes": "access_as_user",
    "ClientSecret": "{CLIENT-SECRET}",
    "ClientCertificates": [],
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "b2c_1_social_susi"
}
```

There is a clear reference in these settings to **b2c** stuff. I would like to know what these settings would look like for a **standard Azure AD** (Not the B2C type)?

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

> I would like to know what these settings would look like for a  **standard Azure AD**?

```cs
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "*****",
    "TenantId": "***",
    "ClientId": "***",
    "ClientSecret" : "***"
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
```

The  `appsettings.json`  file looks like below:

[image]

You can find the  **Azure AD Domain**  in the Portal like below:

[image]